# Unable to connect to SQL Server during Sharepoint AutoSPInstall

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I'm trying to install Sharepoint using autospinstall, however it keeps failing

- Testing access to SQL server/instance/alias: 192.168.1.224\MSSQLSERVER

  - Trying to connect to '192.168.1.224\MSSQLSERVER'
  - Using connection string 'Server=192.168.1.224\MSSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;'...Failed
    WARNING: Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall.

I've tried this with ServerName, ServerName\Instance, IP Address, IP Address\Instance

Firewall's are turned off on both the sharepoint server and SQL server

I'm able to ping the SQL server from the Sharepoint server, I've also installed SQL Server Management Studio on the Sharepoint server which is able to connect to the target SQL server

However when I try to Telnet 192.168.1.224 1433 it just goes to a blank screen

Checking the SQL server

Netstat -ano I can only see a Listener for 0.0.0.0:1433

```
Netstat -ano | findstr PID
    
    TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4020
    TCP    127.0.0.1:1434         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4020
    TCP    192.168.1.224:1433     192.168.1.223:61026    ESTABLISHED     4020 (Sharepoint Server)
    TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4020
    TCP    [::1]:1434             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4020
    
    SQL Configuration manager \ SQL Server Network Configuration \ Protocols for MSSQLSERVER
    
    TCP/IP: Enabled
    Keep Alive: 30000
    Listen All: Yes
    
    Addresses 
    IP1
    Active: Yes
    Enabled: No
    Address: 192.168.1.224
    TCP Port: 1433
    
    IP2
    Active: Yes
    Enabled: No
    IP Address: ::1
    TCP Port: 1433
    
    IP3
    Active: Yes
    Enabled: No
    IP Address: 127.0.0.1
    TCP Port: 1433
    
    IPAll
    TCP Port: 1433
```

Comment: The telnet connection is behaving correctly (there's no command line like you'd see for IMAP/POP/SMTP mail servers, it's a binary protocol) and proves that tcp/1433 is open and available. Because you have an instance name in your connection string `...\MSSQLSERVER` it's probably trying to query the SQL Browser service using SSRP on udp/1433 and failing to get through. Since you know the port number, and you know that it's open, have you tried specifying either `Server=tcp:192.168.1.224,1433` or even just `Server=tcp:192.168.1.224`?

Comment: Thanks good to know the connection is open, I've tried several different options.
Server=IP Address
Server=IP Address\Instance
Server=Server Name
Server=Server Name\Instance

All return the same error

I've also tried the combinations above and neither work